# C Program int Variable Values gets change after reading a Char Value

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I've just created a small calculator application but I noticed that when I read a char value after reading Int Values that next immediate Int variable gets change. What is the reason to happen that ? Here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){   
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char opr;
    int ans;

    printf("Enter the first number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Enter the second number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    printf("Enter the operater : ");
    scanf("%s", &opr);

    printf("%d \n", num1);
    printf("%d \n", num2);

    switch(opr) {
        case '+':
            ans=num1+num2;
            printf("The addtion of %d and %d is %d", num1, num2, ans);
            printf("\n");
            break;

        case '-':
            ans=num1-num2;
            printf("The substractuon of %d from %d is %d", num2, num1, ans);
            printf("\n");
            break;

        case '*':
            ans=num1*num2;
            printf("The multiplication of %d and %d is %d", num1, num2, ans);
            printf("\n");
            break;

        case '/':
            ans=num1/num2;
            printf("The substraction of %d from %d is %d", num1, num2, ans);
            printf("\n");
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &opr);` is *undefined behavior*

Comment: Any modern compiler wouild warn. Warnings are not for fun, but to be taken seriously. Before asking fix them. (If you don't get warnings, enable them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You have to use `scanf("%c", &opr);` instead of  `scanf("%s", &opr);` Since **opr** is `char` you have to use `%c`, The `%s` is used to scan String .Then the problem of un-handled  `'\n'` issue occurs. So add an extra `'\n'` in-frond of `%c` .Thus the statement becomes `scanf("\n%c", &opr);`;

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    char opr;
    int ans;

    printf("Enter the first number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);

    printf("Enter the second number : ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);

    printf("Enter the operater : ");
    scanf("\n%c", &opr); // not scanf("%s", &opr);

    printf("%d \n", num1);
    printf("%d \n", num2);

    switch (opr)
    {
    case '+':
        ans = num1 + num2;
        printf("The addtion of %d and %d is %d", num1, num2, ans);
        printf("\n");
        break;

    case '-':
        ans = num1 - num2;
        printf("The substractuon of %d from %d is %d", num2, num1, ans);
        printf("\n");
        break;

    case '*':
        ans = num1 * num2;
        printf("The multiplication of %d and %d is %d", num1, num2, ans);
        printf("\n");
        break;

    case '/':
        ans = num1 / num2;
        printf("The substraction of %d from %d is %d", num1, num2, ans);
        printf("\n");
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:-**

```
Enter the first number : 3
Enter the second number : 4
Enter the operater : *
3 
4 
The multiplication of 3 and 4 is 12
```

Comment: Can you explain why if i use scanf("%c", &opr); with out \n it wont work... ? and why %s gives wrong number. Best if you can explain it with some example ... Thanks a lot for the previous answer

Comment: `scanf("%c", &opr);` don't work because there is a `\n` (enter) you pressed for scanning `num2` will be stored to `opr`. To avoid that `\n` , `scanf("\n%c", &opr);` is used .because `\n` is also a char.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanf("%c", &opr)` to read a single `char`.

Using `%s` will read a NUL terminated string, but you have only one byte which is insufficient, leading to undefined behavior.

What's actually happening is that the NUL terminator is being written on top one byte of the `int` variable next to `opr`.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by others a char is read using `%c`:

But you used `%s` so what happens is that scanf reads a string. Assuming normal input for your example that would read one char and a newline. Scanf then writes the char and a terminating 0 byte the address given, which is your char.

But a char is only one byte large and the other spills over onto whatever is next in memory. In your case this happens to be the int variable. This is called a buffer overflow and one of the dangers of using scanf.